# Modeling a Friend relationship in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, social-networking

I am working with GAE and have a user table. Now I want to model friend relationships between users. I am thinking of having 3 properties `user1`, `user2` and `request_status`, but the problem is in querying to find a particular user's friends. Since GAE does not allow `OR` filtering, I have to merge two queries. Clearly that is very inefficient. This is just one problem with my approach.
If someone could suggest a solution that lets me keep track of all friend requests as well as the friendship, then that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Denormalization will let you more efficiently find a user's friends with a single query.  Try storing another property `users` (a `db.ListProperty`) in your model which contains *both* `user1` and `user2`.  Then you can simply execute a query like this to find a user's friends:

```
friendships = Friendship.all().filter('users =', user).fetch(...)
```

The advantage is that you only need a single query (faster).  The disadvantage is that you will have a little extra space overhead to store the `users` property and the (automatic) index on it.

Comment: yeah but the order of user1 and user2 is uncertain, if user A was initiator than it will be user1 else it will be user2,

Comment: The order of the `users` property does not matter.  When you test a `ListProperty` for equality, it tests if *any* of its elements is equal to the value you provided.  So if you store perform the above query, it will return all `Friendship` entities which have either `user1` OR `user2` equal to `user` (assuming you populate `users` correctly).