# Storing user 'friends' in GAE datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to make a facebook sort of social networking site (not a facebook app) for fun using flask and google app engine. I'm currently working out how to store friends in the datastore.

I want it to be somewhat like facebook, in that a user will request to be another's friend and once accepted, they can see each other's  posts. So far it seems like it would be stored like this to me:

```
class Friendship(db.Model):
    user1 = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    user2 = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    request_accepted = db.BooleanProperty()
```

but I saw [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202059/modeling-a-friend-relationship-in-gae), and the many-to-many example on [google's datastore documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) and it has me confused. I have only ever worked with relational databases like mysql before, so I don't really know what they are going on about, but it seems important.

If anyone knows what I should do, please let me know—it would be hugely appreciated. If you need my full `models.py` source code, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a different web portal or facebook application?

Comment: sorry, i should've clarified that. It's not a facebook application, it's a from-scratch social networking site

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong with the model given in your question for the purpose to which you intend to put it.

Comment: OK, I thought there might have been a better way to do it. On a related note, with that model, when running the app engine test server, I get the following error on the line that `class Friendship` is on: `DuplicatePropertyError: Class User already has property friendship_set`

Comment: @tominated it is because you haven't mentioned collection_name in your reference property. By default user will be having property called name_set. Here name is nothing but the model's name which it is referred by. As you are referring to user model twice,it is raising duplicate propertyerror.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying  has nothing to be confused. In your model, an friendship class is having two references of the type user property.

```
freindship=FriendShip()
friendship.user1=#assign a key of user or user object
friendship.user2=#assign a key of user or user object
friendhsip.put()
```

Here user1 and user2 will be referring to some user object. And also add a collection name to your reference attributes to avoid confusion.
To know more have a look here [modeling in appengine](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/er-modeling-with-google-app-engine.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have userid also to be store in Friendship model as that will be useful in case of filtering data accordingly... Otherwise you need to crawl your datastore to find mutual friends... :D

And "When" entity too to show friends in sorted order... :)

```
class Friendship(db.Model):
  user1 = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
  user2 = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
  user1id = db.StringProperty()
  user2id = db.StringProperty()
  request_accepted = db.BooleanProperty()
  when = db.DateTimeProperty()
```